# Controlling multiple Pi's over a network

Tags: networking, pi-3

If I was to set up 10 or more Raspberry Pi 3's with Raspbian Jessie on the same network, is there a way I can control all of them at once?

So all of the Pi's have Raspbian installed and they are all connected to the same network, and they have been given fixed IP addresses.

But what if I want to install Chromium on all of them for example? That would require running the same command on all of the Pi's, that's time consuming.

Is there a way I can send the same commands to all of the Pi's at once from a master computer?

Comment: How is this Pi-related?

Comment: Well, I suppose it may be Pi related, I don't think it's Pi specific though.  It is a standard administration question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Free but professional configuration managment tools like [Puppet](https://puppet.com/) , [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) ,  [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) might fit the bill if you plan to orchestrate a very big fleet of Pis inside your Enterprise.

Or use tools which literally execute a command via SSH on multiple machines :

- [pssh](https://github.com/robinbowes/pssh)
- [pdsh](https://github.com/grondo/pdsh)
- [clusterssh](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh)
- [clusterit](http://clusterit.sourceforge.net/)
- [mussh](http://mussh.sourceforge.net/)